# COGNOS: How can i enable the same sort order for list and chart

Tags: sorting, reporting, cognos

Hello I have following problem. I would like to have the same order for Ratingklasse in the Chart as i it is in the List. The List has no sorting function. The Chart sorts the values correctly but from bottom to top compared to the list. As soon as i use the asc function it displays the values AA before AAA. Hase anyone a clue if i can set up something in the Chart to Show me the exact values but in a different order, expect the sorting function?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide a number that indicates the correct sort order and sort on that. I don't know how your list managed to sort as expected without a sort key. If you sort a string then AA is before AAA. That's why you need to supply a number

Comment: Thank you Nick, i had that also in my mind. But doesnt get the point why the charts sorts differently than the list...

Comment: Even over relational data sources, charts and crosstabs spin temporary dimensional cubes behind the scenes.  This throws off the natural sort order when comparing what comes back in a list versus in a chart/crosstab.

As Nick pointed out, you'll need to create a custom sort order data field and then sort on that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to point the list query to the query for the chart?
(Drag the list query next to the query for the chart)